# Proof of irreducibility of $x^2+1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to prove that $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$. In order to do that, let's say it's not irreducible, then we have:

$x^2+1=(x+a)(x+b) \rightarrow x^2+(a+b)x+ab=x^2+1\mod p$, thus we have:

$a=-b \mod p$, $ab=1\mod p \rightarrow b^2=-1\mod p$

Now, can I say that the last equation doesn't have any answer in $\mathbb{Z}[x]_p$? If yes, how? Because the last equation implies that $b^2 = p-1\mod p$, and I am not sure how to prove there is no $b$ exist to satisfy this equation

Comment: But it's not always irreducible?

Comment: $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_p[x]$ (where $p$ is prime) if and only if $p$ is of the form $4k+3$.

Comment: @user236182 Interesting! but why? Can you provide any proof for that?

Comment: If $p$ is prime, then $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_p[x]$ if and only if (iff) $x^2+1$ has no roots in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$ iff $-1$ is not a quadratic residue mod $p$ iff $p$ is of the form $4k+3$. See [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B11_and_the_first_supplement).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's set $p=5$.

$x^2 +1 \equiv x^2 - 4 \equiv (x-2)(x+2) \pmod 5$.

What's really going on? You have to out find when $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. You should read really carefully this interesting page on Wikipedia about Legendre Symbol and its properties! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol.

Comment: I think I got your point. So, if $p-1$ has a complete square root in $Z_p$, then $x^2+1$ is not irreducible. Otherwise, we can prove that there exists no $b$ which can satisfy $b^2=p-1$ $mod_p$. Please correct me if I am missing something here

Comment: $x^2+1$ is reducible iff it has a root (since it is of degree 2), iff $-1$ is a square.

Answer (score 6):

It is not in general true that $x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]$. For example, we have that $$x^2+1 \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$$ may be written as: $$(x+1)(x+1) \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}[x].$$

Answer (score 2):

To add some details to Maffred's answer, there's actually an exact criterion for this, which is well known as part of the answer to a different question.

**Theorem:** (Fermat's Two Square Theorem) Let $p$ be a prime of $\mathbb{Z}$. The following are equivalent:

1. $\exists x\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p|x^2+1$
2. $p$ is not prime as an element of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$
3. $\exists a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p=a^2+b^2$
4. $p=1\pmod{4}$ or $p=2$